# Angular 6/7 multi application change directory of projects (ng g application module1)

Tags: angular

I am trying to create the structure of an angular / dotnet core application. I use ng generate application to have a main portal and several autonomous applications within the portal (multi SPA).

It works fine 
    ng build srp-module // its my module build ok (without change directory)

but except that I would like to split my projects and put them in specific directories.

By default :

```
PortalRoot:
    - src
    - projects
             - module1
             - module2
```

I would like to have

```
PortalRoot:
    - src
Projects
    - Module1
    - Module2
```

I Change angular.json

```
  "projects": {
    "srp-portal": {
      "root": ""
   },
 "srp-module": {
      "root": "../projects/Module/ClientApp/",
      "sourceRoot": "../projects/Module/ClientApp/src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "srp-module"
 }
```

But when change this and execute   ng build srp-module I have this error

```
Cannot locate node_modules directory.
Error: Cannot locate node_modules directory.
```

how to indicate that the node_module is at the root project level

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is not possible with angular-cli. the root is necessarily where the angular.json file is.